# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx].....Prease

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I am trying
MY pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
<artifactId>NOCMatrixServer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
    <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    <!-- Test -->
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>
                            MatrixServer.MainMethod
                        </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tmax.tibero</groupId>
        <artifactId>tibero-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>D:/Workspace/tibero5-jdbc-14.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>oracle-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>D:/Workspace/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

```
> mvn asem assembly:single
> java -jar NOCMatrixServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I get the following:

```
=2014-11-12 10:15:52,661 INFO [org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext] Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1376c05c: startup date [Wed Nov 12 10:15:52 KST 2014]; root of context hierarchy [] - (AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
=2014-11-12 10:15:52,692 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [MatrixServer/Setup/Context-Application.xml] [] - (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:315)
=2014-11-12 10:15:55,411 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [MatrixServer/Setup/Context-Datasource.xml] [] - (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:315)
=2014-11-12 10:15:56,145 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [MatrixServer/Setup/Context-SqlMap.xml] [] - (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:315)
=2014-11-12 10:15:56,536 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [MatrixServer/Setup/Context-Transaction.xml] [] - (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:315)
D:\Workspace\NOCMatrixServer\target>java -jar NOCMatrixServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar >> 1.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at MatrixServer.MainMethod.main(MainMethod.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
Offending resource: class path resource [MatrixServer/Setup/Context-Transaction.xml]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1435)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at MatrixServer.Init.MatrixServerInit.init(MatrixServerInit.java:16)
        at MatrixServer.Init.MatrixServerInit.<init>(MatrixServerInit.java:12)
        at MatrixServer.Init.MatrixServerInit.<clinit>(MatrixServerInit.java:8)
        ... 1 more
```

Why???? Solve Please........

Comment: For starters don't mix spring versions, you are mixing 3.1.2 and 4.1.1. Next if you are creating an uber jar make sure that you are merging the different spring.schema files. Finally when using namespaces make sure to use the versionless xsd so `spring-tx.xsd` instead of `spring-tx-3.2.xsd`. .

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really enough information here to get the full picture, but check your Spring context configuration and make sure you're using the correct URI.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd"
```

Note that the schema version differs from that of the library.

Comment: Thank you! but Same existing circumstances is achieved even if changed.

Comment: @TristanLudrow Could you please post the contents Context-Transaction.xml, or at least the declaration with all of the relevant namespaces?

Comment: No problem. These types of issues suck. I would maybe try bumping the other schemas up to the correct version (3.0 -> 3.2). There may be some unsatisfied dependency if the 3.0 schemas reference the 3.0 version of spring-tx.

Comment: Discharge without any problem if execute in Eclipe. But > mvn asem assembly:single
java -jar NOCMatrixServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: Check the manifest ("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF") and make sure that the spring-tx library, version 3.2, is on the classpath. Eclipse provides the classpath in a different fashion. If you do not have a manifest, there is a Maven plugin that you can use to generate one. I'll post details if this proves to be an issue.

Comment: @TristanLudrow Just following up. Any updates to report?

Answer (score 0):

Missing jars could cause such problem. See [this](http://www.baeldung.com/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace) for details, e.g. for `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx` namespace add the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```